# Can not Upload file inside folder using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, file

I have an issue while uploading the file inside project folder.I am explaining my code below.

```
$imageName=generateRandomNumber().'_'.$_FILES["uploadme"]["name"];
$target_dir = "upload1/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($imageName);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["uploadme"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
      if (file_exists($target_file)) {
      echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
   if ($_FILES["uploadme"]["size"] > 500000) {
      echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
    }
   // Allow certain file formats
   if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
      && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
      echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
   }
  // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
  if ($uploadOk == 0) {
     echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
   // if everything is ok, try to upload file
  } else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadme"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["uploadme"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
  }
```

Here i am getting the image and adding one random number with it But while uploading the image could not save inside the `upload1` folder.Here i am getting the `Sorry, there was an error uploading your file` message.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: check the permission of folder.

Comment: make sure your folder path is correct from the location of script file

Comment: Are you using the linux operating system? If so than this is the folder permission issue. Execute this "sudo chmod 777 -R folder-path" command in terminal

Comment: add `var_dump(error_get_last())` to the else part, have a look at the error and fix it

Comment: Permission has already there for that folder.

Comment: subhra, did you try @KhomeHoly's suggestion? What did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Give permission to the folder by right clicking the folder and selecting the permission tab and then give the permission to folder by allowing creating and deleting files from folder.